# Spring Liquibase tries to resolve file path to URL

Tags: spring, liquibase

I configured liquibase like this:

```
@Bean
public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setDataSource(getConfiguredDataSouce());
    liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath*:config/liquibase/master.xml");
    liquibase.setContexts("development,test,production");
    LOG.debug("Configuring Liquibase");

    return liquibase;
}
```

my master.xml file:

```
<includeAll path="classpath*:/config/liquibase/changelog/" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
```

When I run my application on Tomcat (7.0.50 and 8.0.20) it prints this exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [D:/proiecte/ALE MELE/Rezervari/target/Rezervari/WEB-INF/classes/config/liquibase/changelog/20150329182213.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
at   org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:178)
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase$SpringResourceOpener.getResourcesAsStream(SpringLiquibase.java:109)
at liquibase.util.StreamUtil.singleInputStream(StreamUtil.java:181)
at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:93)
... 73 more
```

That file exists on that path, but it tries (for I don't know what reason) to resolve it to an URL. 
Any ideas? :)

P.S.: Liquibase version is 3.2.2.

Thank you,
Tekin.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was in extra slash (local, MacOS):

"classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/" - works well.

"classpath:/config/liquibase/changelog/" - does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the same as [CORE-2186](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2186?filter=-2&jql=watcher%20%3D%20currentUser%28%29%20ORDER%20BY%20createdDate%20DESC) on the Liquibase Jira. I get the same symptoms when trying to use `includeAll` running from Ant.

The original reporter on that bug has added a proposed fix, though just as a comment to the report. I haven't tried it yet.