# maven liquibase plugin not ignoring leading / in filepath

Tags: spring-boot, maven, liquibase

I have spring boot setup to execute liquibase changes on postgresql database.

1) In DB the **filename** column (**databasechangelog** table) is updated with leading "/" ( example : /db/changelog/changesets/changelog.xml).

2)when trying to execute update from maven liquibase plugin the leading "/" is not detected and tries to execute the same changelog file again. Which ends up throwing error.

3)when trying to execute rollback from maven. It will not do anything as filename with leading "/" is not detected.

How to overcome this issue. Can't we tell sprint boot application to insert filename without leading "/" or how to tell maven to consider leading "/" ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321884/spring-liquibase-tries-to-resolve-file-path-to-url, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51876435/adding-extra-backslash-in-the-column-value-in-the-generated-sql-file-from-genera all are about this issue

Comment: @AbinashGhosh there are is no solution to what i have asked here.

Comment: Actually its bug of liquibase how can you get a solution.